# Control source IIF statement invalid syntax error

Tags: ms-access

I am using an IIF statement as a control source for a text box and am getting
"The expression you entered contains invalid context"
"You may have entered and operand without an operator"

Here is my statement

```vb
=if([ExitDate] IsNull,(DateDiff("d", [EntryDate],now())),(DateDiff("d", [EntryDate], [ExitDate])))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if(` with `iif(`

There is a function, `IsNull()`.  If you want to test whether `[ExitDate]` is Null, feed it to the function like this: `IsNull([ExitDate])`

But it looks like you want `DateDiff` between `[EntryDate]` and `[ExitDate]`, except substituting today's date for `[ExitDate]` when it is Null.  If that's correct, use a simpler more direct expression for the control source.

```vb
=DateDiff("d", [EntryDate], Nz([ExitDate], Date()))
```